# Batch File input validation integer number

Tags: batch-file

I want to tell  a user  to input just how many minutes he wants before shutting down the computer and I don't know how can I avoid any letter in the user input. I just want to allow a number otherwise go to finish

```
@ECHO OFF

pushd %systemroot%
echo *{Enter the number of minutes  required before Turn off the computer then press (enter)}
set/p "x="


if %x% EQU %x% set/a z= 60*%x%
echo %z%
shutdown -s -t %z%


echo finish
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

pushd %systemroot%
echo *{Enter the number of minutes  required before Turn off the computer then press (enter)}
set/p "x="

SET "notnumber=9%x%"
FOR /l %%z IN (0,1,9) DO CALL SET "notnumber=%%notnumber:%%z=%%"
IF DEFINED notnumber ECHO entry was NOT a number&GOTO :EOF 

set/a z= 60*%x% 2>NUL
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO invalid number entered&GOTO :EOF 
echo %z%
ECHO shutdown -s -t %z%


echo finish
GOTO :eof
```

Note that batch regards a number that starts `0` as OCTAL, so entering `09` is invalid (because it's not octal) and entering `013` is valid, but will give a timeout of 11 minutes because `13` octal is `11` decimal.

Note also that the `shutdown` command is simply `echo`ed to avoid shutting down during testing.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another method:

```
@ECHO OFF
pushd "%systemroot%"
:loop
"set x="
set /p "x=Enter the number of minutes required before Turn off the computer then press (enter) "
rem this allows the user to press enter to quit without doing anything
if not defined x goto :EOF
rem check for numerals only - else loop to start again
set "num="
for /f "delims=0123456789" %%a in ("%x%") do set "num=%%a"
if defined num goto :loop

set /a z=60*%x%
echo %z%
shutdown -s -t %z%

echo finish
```